# Swift: String comparison with ==

Tags: swift

Why this doesn't work?
I am trying to compare two string with == , usually it works but when doing it like this it is not working

```
if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

    if utf8Text == "success" {
        //it wont get in this block even if the utf8Text is success
    }
}
```

why this doesn't work and how will we make it match?

Comment: what is the exact output of  **utf8Text**?

Comment: It doesn't work because `utf8Text != "success"`. Check the string for leading or trailing whitespace or newline characters. Is `utf8Text.count` == 7 ? Please add the output of `print(response.data as NSData)`

Comment: Data: success  this is the output for print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below

```
String(utf8Text).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "success"
```